# Value minimizing mean absolute percentage error

Tags: calculus, optimization, error-function, mean-square-error

What value for $c$ would minimize the formula:

$$\frac{1}{n}\;\sum^{n}_{i=1}\left | \frac{y_i-c}{y_i}\right|$$

given the values $y_1, ..., y_n$. For example in the mean squared error we have the minimizing value for $c$ is the mean value of the given data $c = \mu = \displaystyle\frac{y_1+\cdots + y_n}{n}$. What would be the equivalent value for $c$ in this case? Does an analytical solution exist?

wikipedia reference:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_percentage_error

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I do not know in which context you need this property but, as very well answered by Peter Kosinar, the result will correspond to one of the data points and the solution will not be immediatly obtained. Could you clarify the goal ? Thanks.

Comment: Goal is just for personal interest :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If considered as function of $c$, the expression is piecewise-linear, with breaking points precisely at points $y_i$. Thus, it attains its minimum value at one of the points $y_i$. Depending on the actual values of $y_i$, the point $c$ point might be determined uniquely, or it might lie within a closed interval delimited by two neighbouring $y_i$s (for example, $y=(2,3,6)$ is minimized by any $c\in \langle 2,3\rangle$).

Algorithmically, it's easy to find the point in linear time:

1. Sort the values $y_i$ in ascending order.
2. Compute the quantity $S:=-\sum\limits_{1\leq i\leq n} \frac{1}{|y_i|}$
3. Process the points one by one and when processing point $y_i$, update $S$ by adding $\frac{2}{y_i}$ to it.
4. When $S$ changes its sign from negative to positive, the point you just processed is your desired $c$. If the value $S$ happens to be equal to zero, the possible values of $c$ lie anywhere between the processed and next-to-be-processed point.

The value $S$ represents the *slope* of the linear segment; which changes whenever we cross one the given points $y_i$. The initial value of the slope corresponds to "everything negative", the final value of "everything positive"; so there must be a point when it changes sign.

Answer (score 1):

you obviously run into problems in $y_i = 0$ so lets suppose $y_i > 0$.  you know that the median minimizes $\sum | X_i - a|$ over all a, so choose c so that $1 =$ median $ \frac c {y_i}$, and that actually makes $c = $ median $y_i$

Comment: Consider $y=(2,3,4,6,12)$. Your approach suggests that the right answer is $c=4$, while the correct one should be $c=3$.

Comment: you are right, that is not correct